# How to log in as a user from admin panel?

Tags: authentication, odoo, odoo-9

Is there a function to log in as a user so that I can clearly see the user's authentication.

I could make a user for test with same authentication to see what the user can see and do.

But as a developer, If there is a function, I'd like to use but If not, I'd like to develop.

Please let me know how to do

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This OCA module will give you what you need. Let's you masquerade as any user in the system. Believe OCA has ported it to all versions of 6+ as well.

https://github.com/OCA/server-tools/tree/10.0/auth_admin_passkey